# cordova app build error Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons

Tags: node.js, html, cordova, phonegap

When i tried to build cordova app this error will occur.please help me to solve.

```
C:\Users\Rajadurai\Desktop\hello>cordova build
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Rajadurai\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102
studio
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 27.744 secs
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar
```

Comment: Did you found the solution?